# Foreign Key Constraint when archiving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, archive

I have `Student` and `Archive` tables. The `Archive` table has a foreign key which is the `Student`'s `Id`.

When I click the `Archive` button, the student is added to the archive button but I need to remove the student from the student's table as well.

The problem is that the foreign key constraint forbids me from doing that.

Are there any suggestions?

I am using ASP.NET MVC, C#, Entity Framework code-first.

Comment: why would the Archive table have a FK with the table that the data is coming from?

Comment: @Claies because I need to link the two tables and I need that Id for that link unless you suggest another method

Comment: why do they need to be linked? normally an archive is a copy of an active table, it's not holding different data that has to be included in table joins?

Comment: the answer was right infront of me, I just realized what I was doing wrong. Thank you for pointing out that archive is a "copy" of the active table